# javascript function causing postback on asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, code-behind

This following javascript is causing an unwanted  postback on asp.net webform codebehind:

```js
mini_cal.on("click, focusin", ".a-date", function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass('blurred'))
showEvent($(this).data('event'));
});`
```

It's from a calendar control and the function is called when you click on a date. Adding e.preventDefault() stops the postback but then showEvent() is not called. On a plain html page everything works fine, but I need this on an aspx page cause I need to pull the events from db, server side. I hope someone could come up with a solution, since the author himself does not seem to be able to come up with one.

Ok, here's the aspx page:

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="caltest.aspx.vb" Inherits="caltest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mini-event-calendar.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/mini-event-calendar.js?v=7"></script>

 <script>
     var db_events = [
      {
          title: "Board members meeting.",
          date: 1532381440036,
          link: "events.com/ev2"
      },
         {
             title: "Delaware branch opening.",
             date: 1532467961534,
             link: "events.com/ev1"
         },
         {
             title: "An important event.",
             date: 1532554405128,
             link: "events.com/ev1"
         }
     ];

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#calendar").MEC({
             calendar_link: "example.com/myCalendar",
             events: db_events
         });

         //if you don't have events, use
         //  $("#calendar2").MEC();
     });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h3>With events...</h3>
 <div id="calendar" runat="server" style="width: 30%;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"></div> <br>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

mini-event-calendar.js

```js
(function( $ ) {
 var calenderTpl = '<div id="calTitle"><button class="month-mover prev"><svg fill="#FFFFFF" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg></button><div id="monthYear"></div><button class="month-mover next"><svg fill="#FFFFFF" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg></button></div><div><div id="calThead"><div>S</div><div>M</div><div>T</div><div>W</div><div>T</div><div>F</div><div>S</div></div><div id="calTbody"></div></div><div id="calTFooter"><h3 id="eventTitle">No events today.</h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="calLink">ALL EVENTS</a></div>';
 var short_months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
 var today = new Date();
 var cur_month = today.getMonth();
 var cur_year = today.getFullYear();

    $.fn.miniEventCalendar = $.fn.MEC = function(options) {
     var settings = $.extend({
      calendar_link : "",
      events: []
        }, options );

        var mini_cal = this;

        mini_cal.addClass('mini-cal').html(calenderTpl);

        var tbody = mini_cal.find("#calTbody");
  var cal_title = mini_cal.find("#monthYear");
  var cal_footer = mini_cal.find("#calTFooter");
        var event_title = mini_cal.find("#eventTitle");
  var events_link = mini_cal.find("#calLink");

  cal_title.text("Feb 2018");
        event_title.text("No events today.");
  events_link.text("ALL EVENTS");
  events_link.attr("href", settings.calendar_link);

  if(!settings.calendar_link.length && !settings.events.length)
   cal_footer.css("display", "none");

  mini_cal.find(".month-mover").each(function(){
   var mover = $(this);
   mover.bind("click", function(){
    if(mover.hasClass("next"))
     viewNextMonth();
    else
     viewPrevMonth();
   });
  });

  mini_cal.on("click, focusin", ".a-date", function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('blurred'))
          showEvent($(this).data('event'));
  });

  function populateCalendar(month, year) {
   tbody.html("");
   cal_title.text(short_months[month] + " " + year);

   cur_month = month;
   cur_year = year;

   var ldate = new Date(year, month);
   var dt = new Date(ldate);

   if(ldate.getDate() === 1 && dt.getDay() != 1)
     tbody.append(last_prev_month_days(dt.getDay()));

   while (ldate.getMonth() === month) {
        dt = new Date(ldate);

        var isToday = areSameDate(ldate, new Date());
        var event = null;
        var event_index = settings.events.findIndex(function(ev) {
         return areSameDate(dt, new Date(ev.date));
        });

          if(event_index != -1){
           event = settings.events[event_index];

           if(isToday)
            showEvent(event);
          }

        tbody.append(date_tpl(false, ldate.getDate(), isToday, event));

        ldate.setDate(ldate.getDate() + 1);

        var buffer_days = 43 - mini_cal.find(".a-date").length;

          if(ldate.getMonth() != month)
           for (var i = 1; i < buffer_days; i++)
          tbody.append(date_tpl(true, i));
       }
   }

   function last_prev_month_days(day){
    if(cur_month > 0){
        var month_idx = cur_month - 1;
        var year_idx = cur_year;
       }else{
        if(cur_month < 11){
         var month_idx = 0;
         var year_idx = cur_year + 1;
        }else{
         var month_idx = 11;
         var year_idx = cur_year - 1;
        }
       }
       
       var prev_month = getMonthDays(month_idx, year_idx);
       var last_days = "";
         for (var i = day; i > 0; i--)
        last_days += date_tpl(true, prev_month[ prev_month.length - i]);

         return last_days;
   }

  function date_tpl(blurred, date, is_today, event){
   var tpl = "<div class='a-date blurred'><span>"+date+"</span></div>";

   if(!blurred){
          var cls = is_today ? "current " : "";
          cls += event && event !== null ? "event " : "";
          
          var tpl ="<button class='a-date "+cls+"' data-event='"+JSON.stringify(event)+"'><span>"+date+"</span></button>";
   }

   return tpl;
  }

  function showEvent(event){
   if(event && event !== null && event !== undefined){
    event_title.text(event.title);
    events_link.text("VIEW EVENT");
    events_link.attr("href", event.link);
   }else{
    event_title.text("No events on this day.");
    events_link.text("ALL EVENTS");
    events_link.attr("href", settings.calendar_link);
   }
  }

  function viewNextMonth(){
   var next_month = cur_month < 11 ? cur_month + 1 : 0;
   var next_year = cur_month < 11 ? cur_year : cur_year + 1;

   populateCalendar(next_month, next_year);
  }

  function viewPrevMonth(){
   var prev_month = cur_month > 0 ? cur_month - 1 : 11;
   var prev_year = cur_month > 0 ? cur_year : cur_year - 1;
   
   populateCalendar(prev_month, prev_year);
  }

  function areSameDate(d1, d2) {
   return d1.getFullYear() == d2.getFullYear()
          && d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth()
          && d1.getDate() == d2.getDate();
  }

  function getMonthDays(month, year) {
       var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
       var days = [];
       while (date.getMonth() === month) {
          days.push(date.getDate());
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
       }
       return days;
  }

  populateCalendar(cur_month, cur_year);

        return mini_cal;
    };
 
}( jQuery ));
```

mini-event-calendar.css

```css
.mini-cal{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 1.2em;
    background: #22252e;
    color: #fff;
}

#calTitle{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.12em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.4em 1em;
    padding-top: 0.8em;
}

#calTitle button{
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0.1em solid #ddd;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#calTitle button svg{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#calTitle button:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

#calThead, #calTbody{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0.1em;
}

#calThead{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.88em;
}

#calThead > div, #calTbody .a-date{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: calc(100% / 7);
    max-width: calc(100% / 7);
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

#calThead > div{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
}

#calTbody{
    color: #ddd;
}

#calTbody .a-date > span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#calTbody .a-date{
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 0.1em solid transparent;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

#calTbody .a-date.blurred{
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#calTbody .a-date.event:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.2em;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fffc23;
    width: 0.3em;
    height: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#calTbody .a-date.current{
    border-color: #fffc23;
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
}

#calTbody .a-date.current.event{
    background-color: #fffc23;
    color: #000;
}

#calTbody .a-date:focus,
#calTbody .a-date:active{
    background: #3f4042;
}

#calTFooter{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

#calTFooter #calLink{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.6em 0.8em;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fffc23;
}

#calTFooter #calLink:hover{
    background-color: #555;
}

#calTFooter #eventTitle{
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

Comment: Could you post your full code with html?

Comment: Hi, did you have time to look at the complete code yet? Here's the original repo, in case you migth wanna take a look: https://github.com/jesstrux/jquery-mini-event-calendar